# SQL date in file name

Tags: date, filenames

I am trying to take backup via script

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MITxxxx] TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobile Inventory System\MITxxx' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'MITXXX-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Above query works fine, But I want to add date in file name like

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MITXXX] TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobile Inventory System\MITXXXX_'+ GETDATE() WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'MITXXX-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

But I get error as

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '+'. Msg 319,
>   Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If
>   this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause
>   or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be
>   terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something very similar in an automated backup script:

```
DECLARE @dateDrive VARCHAR(64)
SET @dateDrive=FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMMdd')

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
SET @SQLString=
    N'BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName]
        TO DISK=N''W:\Database Backups\AutoBackups\DatabaseName{DateDrive}.bak''
        WITH INIT
            , NAME=N''DatabaseName-Backup''
            , NOFORMAT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10'

SET @SQLString=REPLACE(@SQLString, '{DateDrive}', @dateDrive)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

I think the key line here is SET @dateDrive=FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMMdd').